# Understanding summation with variables

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem

For a variable x, we have (where a1 is just the first answer box and a2 is the second answer box)

$$(x+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(a_1)^{a_2}$$

what does $a_1$ and $a_2$
equal?
I'm not even entirely sure I understand all of the notation, or what is happening to the $(x+1)^n$

I tried to just think about how to write that equation as a summation, and ended up thinking that $a_1 = x + 1$ and $a_2 = k$, just because n would be replaced by k, starting from 0 all the way up to n, but I really have no idea.

Comment: Apply the standard binomial theorem for $(a+b)^n$ to $(x+1)^n$.

Comment: So I apply it and  get (n choose k)$x^{n-k}1^k$. How do I put the $1^k$ into the exponent? also, what does the $nCk$ mean here?

Comment: How is this related to [tag:integration] or [tag:measure-theory]?

Comment: Integration is just the explanation of summation, so I was wondering if there was something to do with integration. Measure theory came up whenever I looked up topics related to summation.

Comment: @TizzleRizzle I think it's safe to say this has nothing to do with integration or measure theory; I would suggest adding the tag [tag:binomial-theorem] instead.

Comment: Thank you! had no idea lol

Comment: @TizzleRizzle The nCk is called a binomial coefficient, they are also the numbers in Pascal's triangle. If you simplify $1^k$ you should be good to go.

Comment: What do I simplify the $1^k$ to? just 1?

Comment: The problem can be routinely solved by applying elbow grease.  That is, for $n \in \{2,3,4\}$, manually expand $(x + 1)^n$ on scratch paper, look for a pattern, and use that pattern to answer the question.

Comment: See also [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).